# Date() function in javascript giving NAN-NAN-NAN in firefox and chrome while working fine with IE

Tags: javascript

I am calculating on date part through java script , but it is giving NAN-NAN-NAN in Firefox and chrome while working fine in IE . My code is below which is i am using.

```
var datedisp = $("#txtDateinputBox_startdate").val();
datedisp = datedisp.split("/");
var month = datedisp[0];
var year = datedisp[2];
var dtepart = eval(datedisp[1]);
var moddate = dtepart + SetID - 1;
var finaldate = month + '-' + moddate + '-' + year;

var disp_fdate = new Date(finaldate);
//alert(finaldate);
var disp_date = disp_fdate.getDate();
//var disp_date = disp_fdate.getUTCFullDate();
var disp_month = disp_fdate.getMonth() + 1;
var disp_year = disp_fdate.getYear();
var uidate = eval(disp_month) + '-' +eval( disp_date) + '-' + eval(disp_year);
```

and then this uidate is using in div creation.
Please Help 
Thanks In Advance

Comment: What's the value of `$("#txtDateinputBox_startdate").val()`?

Comment: And why are you calling `eval()`? Those arguments already are primitive literals, you don't need to eval them.

Comment: The value of $("#txtDateinputBox_startdate").val()  is date pick from calender on the page for example 01/27/2012

Comment: i am using eval() to add value in date part

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? For instance, for the input `'01/27/2012 '`, how should the result look like?

Comment: i want to manipulate date next setid is a variable in loop above code is in a for loop where every time setId increase , i want result 01/28/2012 , 01/29/2012, .... up to 14 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
var date, i, string;

function date_to_string( date ) {
    return ( date.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
}

date = new Date( '01/27/2012' );

for ( i = 0; i < 14; i += 1 ) {
    date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
    string = date_to_string( date );
    // use string
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ekaDg/

Comment: this helps and i use var datedisp = $("#txtDateinputBox_startdate").val();
    datedisp = new Date(datedisp);var disp_fdate = new Date(datedisp.setDate(datedisp.getDate() + SetID - 1));uidate = disp_fdate.toString();