# Date functions not running in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a date picker through which I get date through the javascript.

```
var tmpEarTxt = document.getElementById('<%=txtEarDate.ClientID %>');
```

When I increment the date by 30 days, the mozilla browser gives NaN-Nan-0NaN as a result. However, its working fine in chrome. Here is my code :

```
var dtVal = new Date(tmpEarTxt.value);
dtVal.setDate(dtVal.getDate() + 30);
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Values outside the 1-31 range are illegal by the specs.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033625/date-function-in-javascript-giving-nan-nan-nan-in-firefox-and-chrome-while-wor

Answer (score 0):

Values outside the 1-31 range are illegal as an argument to [`Date#setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate). You can use [`Date#setTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) and [`Date#getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) instead:

```
var TI_DAY = 1000*60*60*24; //convenience constant; use any notation you like
///
var dtVal = new Date(tmpEarTxt.value);
dtVal.setTime(dtVal.getTime() + 30 * TI_DAY);
```

---

Also make sure you pass the correct string to the Date constructor. See [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and the referenced [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) for the list of valid formats.

The following formats are allowed. The first one works since ES1, the latter ones only work since ES5 (lines 2 & 5 tested in IE8, not supported):

```
Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT
1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00
1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
1997-07-16                    (year-month-day)
1997-07
1997
```

So, **only `new Date("25 Dec 1995")` works everywhere** (tested in IE8, IE9, FF, Chrome)
`new Date("1995-12-25")` works everywhere except IE (tested in IE8, IE9, FF, Chrome)
`new Date("12-25-1995")` works in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.
Additionally, IE (but not Chrome) allows both the day and the month overflow, incrementing the next largest measure, but *only* when parsing the last format (the one not endorsed by MDN). It even lets the year drop below 1900.

Comment: @user1844205 perhaps you have another issue as well, not present in the code you posted.

Comment: I have just this code, its running perfectly in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: @user1844205 I've just noted you take the value of a value of an element. That's not good.

Comment: @user1844205 do you mean the code in your question is not authentic?

Comment: It is, i was wrongly getting the values twice. But still same problem.

Comment: @user1844205 what is in the input box?

Comment: The input is the date for e.g. '02-27-2013'

Comment: @user1844205 firefox does not like that date string. Will investigate.

Comment: So, what's the solution bro?

Comment: @user1844205 updated. Where documentation comprehension fails, testing saves the day.